# MySQL 8.0 on Google Cloud SQL: How to set per-database permissions

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, mysql-8.0

I have a MySQL 8.0 database on Google Cloud SQL. I have two applications accessing two different databases on the same MySQL instance. I'm trying to set up access control so that each application has its own user and that user has access only to one of the databases. However, when I create a new user using the Cloud SQL interface, that user has access to all of the databases on the MySQL instance.

[Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users) gives the following information:

> In MySQL 8.0 for Cloud SQL, when you create a new user, the user is automatically granted the `cloudsqlsuperuser` role. The `cloudsqlsuperuser` role is a Cloud SQL role that contains a number of MySQL privileges. This role gives the user all of the MySQL static privileges, except for SUPER and FILE.

Is it possible to remove this `cloudsqlsuperuser` role from the user and give the user access to the databases individually? And how is this done?

Comment: Its not quite clear, are you creating a System user account or just a user account WITHIN MySQL?

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I check this?

Comment: Are you adding a user to MySQL using MySQL?

Comment: I'm adding users using the process described here https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users#creating using the Console. I'm using "Built-in authentication" rather than "Cloud IAM".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the Cloud SQL API, you will add user at the Cloud SQL level (as the root user, the superuser role).

If you want to manage users and permission inside the database, you must log into the database (using a superuser account) and create your user in the database and grant them inside the database. You can't do that outside (by API call, terraform or something else).

And yes, it's boring for the automation.